# mathematical analysis books for self study

Tags: analysis, reference-request

I am looking for mathematical analysis books whose explanation is polite. If they has many familiar example, I will be happier.

I am familiar with set theory, group theory, elementary theory, but am not familiar with analysis at all.

Comment: Have you covered single and multi-variable calculus? Also: "polite" means "courteous", which is something I hope all authors strive to be - perhaps you mean something like books whose explanations are "gentle" or "easy to follow"?

Comment: What do you mean by "elementary theory"? Also, do you have any relationship with the authors of these previous questions? [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/418439/8348), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420865/8348), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420882/8348), [4](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420888/8348), [5](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/421932/8348), [6](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/417167/8348).

Answer (score 1):

A first Course in Real Analysis by Sterling K Berberian

Answer (score 1):

You don't indicate anything about your interests and goals. A very accessible and concrete book, focusing almost entirely on $\mathbb R$, is Arthur Mattuck's *Introduction to Analysis*.

Answer (score 1):

Terence Tao - Analysis I 
Really great and easy understandable book !

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000SEKU2G) is a nice book for beginners. The book has many interesting examples and the material is nicely motivated.

Answer (score 0):

Tom A. Apostol Calculus part I and II both are good.
Also authour has few more books about Analysis

Answer (score 0):

My favourite book for a first course in (real) analysis is Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis by far. The exposition is very clean and gentle.

For the complex side of things I quite like Ahlfors but this is not to everyone's taste.

Comment: Quite, quite far from gentle. And not a single picture. I've taught students out of this book and most of them definitely need a dedicated teacher.