# The "I wish I had read that first" textbook list

Tags: education, big-list

Here, I am trying to collect as many "I wish I had read that textbook first" textbook names as possible, for as many different topics in mathematics as possible.

The "I wish I had read that textbook first" criterion is when you've already mastered some topic and in retrospect, you can see that "Textook X written by Y" is the best starting point in learning that topic, and most of your peers agree.

Comment: @alex811: See:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94827/what-books-must-every-math-undergraduate-read, https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4026/deep-maths-books, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417167/mathematical-books, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-mathematician-should-read/1550, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674257/most-useful-books-for-a-math-undergrad?rq=1, http://www.ams.org/notices/200510/comm-fowler.pdf, https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm

Answer (score 1):

I surely wish I has read Katsumi Nomizu' *Fundamentals of Linear Algebra* before any other textbook written about that subject.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had *The Joy of Sets* by Keith Devlin when l started learning set theory

I also wish I bought Croom’s *Princples of Topology*
It is an excellent book.

Comment: Obviously someone isn’t a fan of Prof. Devlins work. Lol

Comment: It makes no sense to downvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Gaussian processes, without a doubt the first text should be *Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning* by Rasmussen and Williams.

Comment: It makes no sense to down vote this answer